# Mapping configuration using elasticsearch-dsl DocType

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm developing a simple nlp tool, and using elasticsearch-dsl as a es tool with django.

I will have two "DocType", Entity and Intent. I have created my own analyzer which is:

```
turkish_stop = token_filter('turkish_stop', type='stop', stopwords="_turkish_")
turkish_lowercase = token_filter('turkish_lowercase', type='lowercase', language="turkish")
turkish_stemmer = token_filter('turkish_stemmer', type='stemmer', language='turkish')

turkish_analyzer = analyzer('turkish_analyzer', tokenizer='whitespace', filter=['apostrophe', 'asciifolding',
                                                                                turkish_lowercase, turkish_stop,
                                                                                turkish_stemmer])
```

In each doc, i have a custom mapping, for example;

```
class Entity(DocType):
    entity_synonyms = String(analyzer=es.turkish_analyzer, include_in_all=True)
    entity_key = String(index='not_analyzed', include_in_all=False)

    class Meta:
        index = es.ELASTICSEARCH_INDEX
        doc_type = es.ELASTICSEARCH_ENTITY_DOCTYPE
```

According to document http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/persistence.html#persistence . Entity.init() will create mapping for this doc. It really creates mapping on my es (only for entity doc! :( ) . However, i could not do same thing with Intent, after Entity.init(). 
It gives below error:

```
IllegalOperation: You cannot update analysis configuration on an open index, you need to close index nlp first.
```

Any idea to solve this ? I really want to use Entity.init() and Intent.init() if it is possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to define new `analyzers` for your Intent type on an open `index`. This is not allowed and hence you are seeing the error.

You have to first [`close`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-open-close.html) the index, then run

```
Intent.init()
```

and reopen the index. You can refer to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#update-settings-analysis) for more info.

**EDIT 1** You have to use low level python [official client](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html?highlight=close#elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.close) to close the index.

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.close(index="nlp")
```

Even the `dsl library` uses it to [test](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/e064eb9782418c81fd780ba1c661e21594748fbe/test_elasticsearch_dsl/test_integration/test_mapping.py#L46) the mapping since it is created on top of python client.

Comment: how can i close it with elasticsearch-dsl ? i could not found a way, i ve already thought about it.

Comment: glad I could help, consider marking the answer as accepted because it will help future readers too

Comment: @erhmutlu use `es = connections.get_connection()` to get the instance and close the index with it.